# Cannot launch Truffle example application

Tags: truffle

1. I installed truffle
2. truffle unbox react
3. truffle develop
4. migrate
5. I added if condition to use injected web3(https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/how-to/truffle-with-metamask/)
6. I added one of the addresses which were output by truffle to metamask and I see balance 100eth in my metamask
7. when I try to send transaction from localhost:3000 I see: pending and then queued, they are always pending
   Please help

Comment: Is truffle develop still running?

Answer (score 0):

I had to reset my Metamask account(Settings -> Advanced -> Reset account) to make it work.